# Testing iOS changes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I want to know one thing: how accurate is the Xcode iOS simulator in representing the actual run time on a physical device? I recently tested an app with a 6.1 deployment target on a device running 6.1 (iPad 2). So far I had been testing on an iPad mini running 8.2 (after building the app in Xcode 6.2 and scaling back the deployment target from 7.1) but was shocked to see that the buttons I made didn't load at all on my physical iPad 2. The buttons instead loaded as blank "old school" iPhone buttons and when I clicked some of them, they crashed the app even though their only functionality was to perform a basic segue.

Should I update my iPad 2 to 8.2/8.3 and try again? I guess I am asking because the iPad 2 isn't technically mine and the owner doesn't want me to update it in fear of loosing data so I'm in a pickle as far as conceiving my next step in development . Does this problem sound at all familiar to anyone or should I just save up and buy my own 2nd testing device and hope for the best?

Comment: You can trust the simulator. It is mostly accurate.

Comment: I hope so. I will get a second device to test asap. Can't wait to test at full capacity. Either way I still wonder why the iPad 2 simulator worked but not the physical iPad 2.

Comment: The simulator is generally trust-worthy 99 times out of 100, but there are definitely situations where I've seen different behaviors or edge-cases appear differently on the iDevice than the simulator.